# Ionic Camera Plugin returns an array instead of ImageURI on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get the base64 image from the Ionic Cordova camera plugin but it returns me an array with the below details

```
MediaFile 
    end: 0
    fullPath: "file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1471377463771.jpg"
    lastModified: null
    lastModifiedDate: 1471377464000
    localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/Pictures/1471377463771.jpg"
    name: "1471377463771.jpg"
    size: 3188654
    start: 0
    type: "image/jpeg"
```

I tried using the fullPath to convert the image to a base64

```
$scope.convertImgToBase64URL = function(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
};
```

But that returns me null. Below is my main call to the camera plugin.

```
$scope.takePhoto = function () {
    var options = {
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    };

    $cordovaCapture.captureImage(options).then(function (imageURI) {
        $scope.convertImgToBase64URL(imageURI[0].fullPath, function (base64Img) {
            $scope.dataImg = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Img;
            $scope.modal.show();
        })
    }, function (err) {
        // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
}
```

Note: If I use Data_URL instead of FILE_URI, it still returns me the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mixed docs for the [capture plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/) and the [camera plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/).
The [capture plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/) takes an object specifying how many images to take

```
var options = { limit: 3 };
```

and it looks your are passing the params corresponding to the [camera plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) instead.

I think you are better off using the [camera plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) instead of that capture one if it's just for taking pictures. Your code would end up like this:

```
var options = {
    quality: 75,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: false,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 720,
    targetHeight: 1280,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
};

cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
    var base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
});
```